# How does this function count the number of nodes in a tree?

Tags: c, recursion, tree

A function to count the number of nodes in a tree.

```
int count(node *t)
{    
    int i;  
    if (t == NULL)         
        return(0);  
    i = 1 + count(t->left) + count(t->right); // recursion occurs address of left node is passed and 
    return(i);                                // continue to pass until whole left node
}                                             // is traversed and the value of t is
                                              // NULL and 0 is returned same for right node counting
                                              // i = 1 + 0 + 0 = 1
```

How is the number of nodes counted ?

Comment: Left node is a subtree. Right node is also a subtree. Function is calling itself and the subtrees are as arguments and count is incremented. Now, when the counter reaches to the leaf, it does not have any child so it returns 0. Meaning `leaf tree has count one`. Now it comes to one level up and result is `1 + left leaf count + right leaf count) = 3`. Similarly, it comes one more level up and gets total count. **Assuming all nodes have left and right child apart from the leaves. Well, concept does not change**

Answer (score 10):

[To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895959/how-does-this-function-count-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-tree/5896142#5896142)

Answer (score 3):

That's a recursive implementation of counting tree nodes. It is called for the root node and returns "one plus number of nodes in left subtree plus number of nodes in the right subtree", that is done recursively until it reaches leaf nodes.

Comment: what i know is it  recursively traverse left sub tree until the last node is found now the value of t is NULL and the value is returned at count(t->left) is zero same for the right sub tree and returns 0 to count(t->right). now addition takes place  i=1+0+0=1; so how it can count the total number of left and right nodes

Comment: @srbh: The key is once a recursive call begins the previous call is hold "on pause" and waits for the recursive call to end and then uses its result. So the call tree first goes down to leaf nodes, then calls start returning in FIFO order and sum up the number of nodes from the subtrees.

Comment: that means a stack is maintained for the recursion call and continues pushing address of each node until the null node is found. then it goes to count(t->right) to find right node until NULL  node is found.Previous address of node is pope out going back to it's parent node now again left and right node is counted and so on. please correct me  where i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The total count includes the current/root node plus the count on the left branch plus the count on the right branch. Your sentinel is the NULL which means you've reached the leaf node of whatever  branch you are currently counting. Then you unwind back up. Recursion :)

Answer (score 1):

First, have you tried it yourself?

Basically, it adds 1 for every non-null node. It's roughly like this: `1 + number_of_nodes_to_the_left + number_of_nodes_to_the_right`. This expands to: `1+(1+number_of_nodes_to_the_left_in_left+number_of_nodes_to_the_right_in_left) + (1+number_of_nodes_to_the_left_in_right + number_of_nodes_to_the_right_in_right)`. Keep on expanding and you'll see that it's basically `1 + 1 + 1 +....` for every non-null node in the tree.

**EDIT**: To illustrate this better, consider the following tree:

```
     Node0
       |
(left) |  (right)
Node1 _|_ Node2
            |
     (left) |  (right)
     Node3 _|_ Node4
```

When you do `int node_count = count(Node0)`, since Node0 is not NULL, it goes to the return statement which is:
`return 1 + count(left) + count(right)`. You need to understand a basic thing that very operation in your recursion function happens one-after-the-other.In other words operation `count(right)` doesn't happen until operation `count(left)` is completed. Now take a look at the return statement you have there and translate it in terms of the above tree. It would be `1+count(Node1)+count(Node2)`. So `count(Node2)` doesn't get calculated before `count(Node1)` has finished. So for `count(Node1)`, count function gets called (again) with Node1 as the argument. So let us, for now, forget about the semi-calculated expression `1+count(Node1)+count(Node2)` (we'll come back to it later).

Now for `count(Node1)`, Node1 is not NULL and hence proceeds to the return statement. This would (again) be `1+count(left)+count(right)`. But wait, Node1 doesn't have left and right nodes. So, when `count(left)` gets called with the argument being NULL, it returns 0 and the same happens for `count(right)`. So the expression for `count(Node1)` becomes `1 + 0 + 0`. There are no more count functions being called for Node1 and hence it **returns to it's original caller**, which was **the return statement of `count(Node0)`**.

Since we have `count(Node1)` figured out, let's replace it in the return statement of `count(Node0)`. This now becomes `1 + (1 + 0 + 0) + count(Node2)`.

Now I'm going to make this a bit faster. Since Node2 has two children, the return statement of Node2 will be `1 + count(Node3) + count(Node4)`. Just like it was for Node1, `count(Node3)` and `count(Node4)` will each return `1 + 0 + 0`, turning the return statement of `count(Node2)` to be `1 + (1 + 0 + 0) + (1 + 0 + 0)`.

Now that `count(Node2)` has been fully calculated, let's **return to the original caller of `count(Node2)`**, which is `1 + (1 + 0 + 0) + count(Node2)`. Replace what we got from `count(Node2)` in there and we get `1 + (1+0+0) + (1 + (1+0+0) + (1+0+0))`. Add it up and we get the value of `5`. **This value gets returned to whichever function that called `count(Node0)`**, like the statement `int node_count = count(Node0)` and `node_count` will have the value `5`.

Comment: what i think is my concept of recursion is not good. but in this  recursion call count(t->left) continues calling itself and proceeding to only left node as the address of left node is passed and finally finding a null value it returns zero to count(t->left).now "t" has a NULL value how does it return back to count the right node. please reply.

Comment: I've added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these trees:

A tree with no nodes (i.e. a NULL pointer) - returns 0

A tree with one node, the root. This will call:

```
 i=1+count(t->left)+count(t->right);
```

with left and right NULL, and so will return 1 + 0 + 0

A tree with a root and a single right leaf

```
 i=1+count(t->left)+count(t->right);
```

will return 1 for the root, 0 for the tree rooted at left (by the rules above)  and 1 for the tree rooted at right (by the rules above), which is 1 + 0 + 1

And so on.